# import huge data using ibatis generate weird error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ibatis

I was trying to import on 1 shot on oracle DB using Ibatis (not myIbatis) 
a huge amount of data but with no success.
below the code :

`<insert id="insertList"  parameterClass="java.util.List">
   begin
<iterate conjunction=" ">
Insert Into TABLE(
        id,
        col1,
        col2) 
    values (
        SEQUENCE.nextval,
        #[].col1#,
        #[].col2#); 
</iterate>
    end;
</insert>`

```
public void insertList(List<TestBean> insertList) throws SQLException
      {
         try
         {
            sqlMap.insert("insertList", insertList);
         }
         catch(SQLException e)
         {
           System.out.Print("error"+e);
         }
      }
```

the error generated was confusing since we did try it on 10g and the result was due to `program is too large` and that make sense.

- on 11g  and am not sure if the error generated is due to db version was that the list sent `insertList` to be commit it in the process did miss behavior work as the values of `col1` in the arrayList took place of `col2`
  i did trace the logs from my `jetspeed` and got what is executement statement and the params sent from ibatis (result was that all the params where right placed and everything look just fine)
- i did execute these statements directly from `pl/sql Developer` and the data were just integrated fine

as solution i did move to a batch file and there is no errors and i got what i need but still wondering about what is the problem that made my List miss behave and lead to try to insert value of `col1` into `col2`

- is it because of ibatis and iteration did corrupt the list ?
- is it from oracle side , oracle did not handle the list well ?
- is it maybe from server side ?
- and finally could i find out how to solve this type of insert ?
- Note : trying this scenario on few records just work fine for me and no errors.

Comment: what error code do you get?

Comment: its not about what error its that the isert go to fill the column with the wrong param ... what actually happens that my final column was set to null and the first column was a foreign key so i got violation constraints key error but it was due to that the foreign key column tried to insert a wrong param(the null param). hopefully i did clarify my point

Comment: @ibre5041 is it clear for you now ?